# Issues with setcookie on wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, setcookie

At first I had my `setcookie()` as:

```
$school = "Some Value";
setcookie("default_school", $school, time()+3600);
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

That didn't work, so I did some searching, and found that I probably just needed to set a path, so I changed it to:

```
$school = "Some Value";
setcookie("default_school", $school, time()+3600, "/", ".mydomain.com");
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

That still didn't work so I did some more investigating, and determined that my issue must just me setting the cookie too late. So I then started checking my if my headers were set in certain parts of my code, which needs to return `bool(false)`.

```
var_dump(headers_sent());
```

First the top of my `index.php`, then at the top of my `header.php`, but still the same result; they both return true?

I feel like this should be so simple, and I'm getting nowhere. A push in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Isaac

EDIT: Just tried putting it before the init hook, and it returned false. I then put the setcookie function there, and still no luck.

EDIT 2: Ended up adding:

```
function set_user_cookie() {
    $school = "Some Value";
    setcookie('default_school', $school, time()+3600);
}

add_action('init', 'set_user_cookie');
```

and now it works perfectly.

Comment: works for me on my local...is your cookie settings off?

Comment: Hhm that's strange, it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug this kind of situation, you should start with enabling proper error reporting (don't use in a production environment):

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

If you subsequently call `setcookie()` it will issue a warning that will tell you where the output has started.

If you can't do that, you can use `headers_sent()` in this manner to figure out where the output has started as well:

```
if (headers_sent($file, $line)) {
    echo "Output started in $file on line $line\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I ended up getting it to work, see EDIT 2.